# Column formatters in Flask Admin interface

Tags: python, flask, macros, jinja2, flask-admin

Hi I have created a Flask admin interface. In one of the field(column), I would like to include a hyperlink.

```
class workout(db.Model):
    equipment = db.Column(db.String(100))
    place = db.Column(db.String(100))
    image = db.Column(db.Text)
```

or using Jinja2 macro in template:

I have to create a view which should include the above columns as well as I have to format the image column in the view.

I am really not so sure of how to create the view for the above mentioned custom class model.

```
from flask_admin.model.template import macro

class WorkoutView(ModelView):
```

in _macros.html file.

```
{% macro render_image() %}
<a href="#" id="upload_widget_opener">Upload images</a>
<script src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">  
  document.getElementById("upload_widget_opener").addEventListener("click", function() {
    cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'mycloudname', sources: [ 'local', 'url', 'camera', 'image_search', 
                 'facebook', 'dropbox', 'google_photos' ], upload_preset: 'myuploadpreset'}, 
      function(error, result) { console.log(error, result) });
  }, false);
</script>

{% endmacro %}
```

IF I run the _macros.html file, it is good and I am getting the hyperlink as expected. 
Issue : I am not getting the hyperlink in the column which I formatted when I try to import the macros from _macros.html file

Is there any issue with my syntax in _macros.html or in app.py file ?

Comment: please mention what is the issue

Comment: Why does `MyModelView` inherit from `db`?

Comment: @SumanKalyan : I am not getting the hyperlink in the image column

Comment: @stamaimer : db is connected with postgresql [ sqlalchemy ]

Comment: You want upload image in list page or edit and create page of Flask-Admin?  And what does cloudinary return to you?

Comment: I want to upload images from the hyperlink of an column in Flask admin (Admin view) and cloudinary returns a widget to upload images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misuse SQLAlchemy and Flask-Admin. CustomModel class inherit from db.Model from SQLAlchemy and CustomModelView class inherit from ModelView from Flask-Admin to control the behavior of that Model in Flask-Admin. You can achieve your purpose as follows:

Use `form_widget_args` to add `id` attribute to form field;

Inherit `create.html` & `edit.html` to add javascript.

```
class ExampleModelView(ModelView):

    # ...

    edit_template = "admin/edit.html"
    create_template = "admin/create.html"

    form_widget_args = {
        "image": {
            "id": "cloudinary"
        }
    }

    # ...

# template inherit. "edit.html" is same as "create.html" except the first line.

{% extends "admin/model/create.html" %}
{% block tail %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script src="https://widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        # js code to upload image and return response
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I am little not clear with the above code.

class ExampleModelView(ModelView):

    # ... IF I create a CustomModelview like this, how can I use the CustomClassModel on which I have to create the view ? 
How to define that only one column in the view has to be formatted ? 
How to use the create.html file which you have shown above to render the changes in the view ?

Comment: At first, The code in the answer only format the `image` field and leave the left fields unchanged. And for the second comment, You can create a Flask-Admin instance first and call the `add_view` method on it: `admin.add_view(ExampleModelView(ExampleModel, db.session))`. For the template file, You can create a directory named `admin` in your templates directory and place the inherited `create.html` and `edit.html` in it.

Comment: @KathiravanNatarajan Okay